# Two variables on the same line for a calculator batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am currently making a batch file to multiply two numbers. Here is my code:

```
@echo off
cls
echo Math Commands
set /p num1= & set /p num2=
set /a sum1="num1 * num2"
cls
echo Your question is %num1% x %num2%= %sum1%  
pause
```

Every time I enter the first number, a new line is created to enter the second number. The solution I am looking for is to multiply them on the same line, e.g the user enters "10 10", instead of 10 and then 10 on the next line. Is there any way of doing this? Thank you!

Comment: To do this, you will need to learn some string manipulation. I'm not sure about splitting strings in batch, but it may be possible using regex and `findstr`

Comment: Use `for /F` command to split the numbers: `set /p numbers=` and `for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in ("%numbers%") do set "num1=%%a" & set "num2=%%b"`

Comment: By the way, a multiplication results in a *product* but not a *sum*... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, in terms of splitting the string and calculating it yourself, you would probably have to write up a string parser or use regex. However, if all you want to do is simple arithmetic, you can directly put the input into the calculation!

```
@echo off
cls
echo Math Commands
set /p "input=Calculate: "
set /a answer=%input%
cls
echo Your question is %input%= %answer%  
pause
```

This should work for all basic calculations (not just multiplication).

Comment: Thank you very much! I am trying to restrict it to just multiplication so I will research the findstr method. However, this method also works very well.

Comment: @HS1881 if you found my answer helpful please do mark it as correct

Answer (score 1):

when I read your question and comments right, you want to input two numbers (separated ba a space, no arithmetic signs)

Use substring substituation to replace the space with `*`

```
set /p "x=Enter two numbers: "
set /a y=%x: =*%
echo %x: = x % = %y%
```

Note: some more Code is needed to avoid Syntax Errors with "nonconform" inputs